# Why my ng-show doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code :

```
<div ng-init="showDetail = false">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="dataTable in arrayTableData">
                <td ng-repeat="data in dataTable.data" ng-click="showDetail = true;">{{data}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="showDetail">
        <button ng-click="showDetail = false">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My variable `showDetail` changes value when you click on a data of the table, but my div `showDetailCell` not appear.

If I change the initialisation of `showDetail` with `true` the detail appear and disappear when you click on the button, but the click on the cell doesn't display `showDetailCell`.

Comment: Each repeated element gets it's own scope so try $parent.$parent.showDetail = true.

Comment: ng-repeat always creates a new scope, so a consequence of this is what @GruffBunny already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` will get its own scope. Due to Javascript inheritance, whenever variable from parent object is assigned in child scope will create new variable. It will no more reference to parent object variable. Better use `.` notation in the scope variable.

Instead of `showDetail`, use `detail.toggle` will solve the problem.